# Matlab symbolic cosine swap arguments

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

When creating a symbolic cosine function in Matlab of the following type:

```
syms q1 q2
c = cos(q2 - q1);
c % variable c is saved as cos(q1 - q2) instead of cos(q2 - q1)
```

I know that the two notations are equivalent from a mathematical point of view, however, I would like the variable c to be saved as `cos(q2-q1)` to get a coherent symbolic computation, because when I differentiate it with respect to say `q1`, I get `-sin(q1-q2)` instead of `sin(q2-q1)` as it should be.

Comment: Just curious, what do you get if you set `c = sin(q2-q1)`? What happens if you differentiate it twice? Does it list the variables in alphabetical order, or in the same order you defined them? I don't have the symbolic toolbox, so I can't help you much I'm afraid, I'm just curious :)

Comment: Also when you define `d = sin(q2 - q1)` you get `-sin(q1 - q2)`. Looks like matlab tries to keep the input arguments in alphabetic order.

Comment: Yep, if you define `d = sin(q2 - q1)` you get `-sin(q1 - q2)`, and if you differentiate it twice you get `sin(q1 - q2)`. I'm searching the documentation to see if there's a way to override this behavior, but I didn't find anything yet.